# Severely Annoying Fishing Pond Glitch?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

Okay, so I'm trying to catch the 15-pound lunker in the fishing pond as an adult to get the Golden Scale (which is frustrating enough in itself, with the way the fishing seems to work...).

I use the fishing rod, and attract the attention of the big fish by the log. Except, EVERY time I lose the fish -- whether it just loses interest, or it bites and I fail to catch it -- it swims to the middle of the pond, and I CANNOT get its interest ever again unless I leave the fishing pond, re-enter, pay again, and make another attempt.

I have to do this EVERY TIME I fail to catch the fish in one try. I've spent hundreds of rupees on this thing. This isn't isolated to just the one fish, either. As far as I can tell, whenever I walk/swim to close to any fish whatsoever (or get its interest and fail to catch it), that fish swims to the middle of the pond and simply becomes un-catchable -- I can't even target the fish anymore.

This is just... SO annoying. Enter, pay, fail, exit, repeat. I'll probably just catch it on the first try by sheer luck before this is answered, but I have to ask if anyone else has had this happen to them, because from what I've seen online, nobody has.

Also, I'm playing the 3DS version. I can't ever remember this happening in the N64 version. =/

EDIT: Just caught the fish. Thank god. After 400+ rupees, 20+ failed attempts, and *literally* (I know because I looked at the clock) 5+ straight minutes of reeling and almost 2 minutes of the thing flopping around at my feet, I caught the friggin' fish.

I'm going to throw this thing at the wall if this happens in Master Quest, too.

Comment: Yeah from what I remember this fish was for more trouble than it should have been. All to get into the ****ing Water Temple http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItOPzuIRLVI&t=2m27s

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a glitch, just unfortunate luck.

You can use the Sinking Lure to catch the Lunker or the Hylian Loach

After catching a **10+ pound fish as Young Link** or a 15+ pound fish as Adult Link, you can find the Sinking Lure. Note that if you catch the Hylian Loach, despite being the heaviest, your fish weight record will not be saved. There are several spots where the Sinker Lure might be in the Fishing Pond at Lake Hylia. The lure is invisible so you must walk over it and get a notification to find it. You will have to find it again if you quit fishing.

- At the source of the river.
- Back flip over the 3 rocks near the poles and river (land on the middle one) at the end of the stream.
- On the large, arched log in the water.
- In the grass along the outside wall.

I'm not sure if the Sinking Lure is available as Adult Link if you make this lure available as Young Link.

Alternatively, the location of your fishing spot can affect the tracking of the fish. Standing in the water in the lily pads will give the Lunker and the Loach better tracking when attempting to catch them. (Not sure on this) but I also believe that "bobbing" the lure by tapping B occasionally, or jiggling your stick left and right can attract the attention of the fish better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing is, I can't use the sinking lure, because catching a 15+ pound fish is what I'm trying to accomplish in the first place, hehe. In any case, I managed to catch the fish, finally, so it probably _was_ just... really, really, bad luck.

Comment: Could you find the Lure as an Adult? As I highlighted, you can find this lure after catching the 10 pounder also makes this appear, but I wasn't sure if it appears as an adult.

Comment: From what I've read (as well as from what I can remember of the official N64 guide that I used to own), you can find the sinking lure as an adult after catching a 15+ pound fish. I caught a 19-pound fish, but I can't find it, and I'm not too inclined to spend a lot of effort on it now that I have no reason to continue fishing. =/

Comment: Well, I'll have to test this myself then (personally I love fishing in this game, so far nothing has quite matched it). For Science!